# Gulp fails on type definitions added via typings while VS2015 has no issue

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, gulp, ionic2

I am trying to develop an app using ***Ionic 2*** and I am facing some problems with ***gulp***. You can take a look at a detailed version of my problem [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/gulp-fails-on-type-definitions-added-via-typings-while-vs2015-has-no-problem/52497/1). I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**.

You can see further explanations for the solutions below in [this answer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/gulp-fails-on-type-definitions-added-via-typings-while-vs2015-has-no-problem/52497/4) on the Ionic Forum.

**Option 1**

Add index.d.ts to the library src field (not recommended) which can be located in *node_modules > ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript > index.js*. For example:

```
src: ['./app/app.ts', './typings/main.d.ts', './typings/index.d.ts'],
```

**Option 2**

Add the references to main.d.ts. For example:

```
/// <reference path="globals/amqplib/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/when/index.d.ts" />
```